# SyntaxError: invalid syntax but followed the WTF documentation and still doesn't accept it

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

Learning python flask and WTF. Been working on the code below based of the documentation and tutorials however cannot seem to locate the error.

Controller.py

```
from flask import Flask, escape, request, render_template, url_for, flash, redirect, send_from_directory, json, jsonify

from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import (StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField, DateTimeField, 
                        RadioField, SelectField, TextField, TextAreaField, SubmitField)

from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo
from form import infoForm


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'asdfghjklqwertyuiop1234567890'

@app.route('/test', methods=['GET','POST'])
def test():
    breed = False 
    form = infoForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        session['breed'] = form.breed.data
        session['neutered'] = form.neutered.data 
        session['mood'] = form.mood.data 
        session['food_option'] = form.food_option.data 
#       breed = form.breed.data
#       form.breed.data = ''
#   return render_template('test.html', form = form, breed = breed)
        return redirect(url_for('/'))
    return render_template('test.html', form = form)
```

forms.py

```
class infoForm(FlaskForm):

    # Used by forms.py essentially  
    breed = StringField("What breed are you?", validators = [DataRequired()])
    neutered = BooleanField("Have you been neutered?"), choices = ['Yes'])
    mood = RadioField('Please choose your mood: '),choices = [('mood_one','Happy'), ('mood_2','Sad')]
    food_option = SelectField(u'Pick your fav food: '), choices = [('chic','Chicken') , ('bf','beef') , ('fish','fish')])   
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

Response I get on my terminal is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/himanshu/Documents/MasterInt/HMSpython/controller.py", line 21, in <module>
    from form import infoForm
  File "/Users/himanshu/Documents/MasterInt/HMSpython/form.py", line 22
    food_option = SelectField(u'Pick your fav food: ', choices = [('chic','Chicken') , ('bf','beef') , ('fish','fish')])    
              ^
```

The arrow is under - after the word `'chic',`

Would like to understand where am I going wrong as I did follow the documentation?

Thank you!

Comment: Your parentheses are not balanced in `inforform`  Those options belong *inside* the function calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got closing parenthesis ')' in wrong place on radiofields and booleanfield. You close the parenthesis before choices.  Maybe that's the problem. 
And put a space after comma, not before.
You can see what i mean down below.

```
class infoForm(FlaskForm):

    # Used by forms.py essentially  
    breed = StringField("What breed are you?", validators=[DataRequired()])
    neutered = BooleanField("Have you been neutered?", choices=['Yes'])
    mood = RadioField('Please choose your mood:', choices=[('mood_one', 'Happy'), ('mood_2', 'Sad')])
    food_option = SelectField(u'Pick your fav food:', choices=[('chic', 'Chicken'), ('bf', 'beef'), ('fish', 'fish')])   
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

Comment: Hey Engin 
I copied the above file and I sill get the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "controller.py", line 21, in <module>
    from form import infoForm
  File "/Users/himanshu/Documents/MasterInt/HMSpython/form.py", line 23
    food_option = SelectField(u'Pick your fav food:', choices = [('chic', 'Chicken'),('bf', 'beef'),('fish', 'fish')])`
Am I still missing something?

Comment: There was another parenthesis " ) " missing on the end of mood  line. That might be the problem from the beginning. I added the missing parenthesis to the code. Can u please copy and try again?